# CSS Animation: Works in Chrome but not in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

In rotate animation, works in Chrome but not in Firefox. Why?

```
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#example {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -moz-animation: rotate 20s linear 0 infinite;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 20s linear 0 infinite;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WsWWY/

Comment: Can you please specify your browsers' version?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Current Firefox implementations fail unless time values of `0` have units. Use `0s` or `0ms`.

http://jsfiddle.net/WsWWY/1/

Note: [The W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values) explicitly allows for the number 0, without units, to be a length value, but it says no such thing for other values. Personally, I hope this changes, but for the time being the Firefox behavior is not incorrect.

Comment: worth trying is that, if we change `20s` to `2ms`, the square does not animate at all.

Comment: @wesley murch thanks for the edits! The iPad keyboard's lack of a backtick key really overflows my stack.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: animation on my FF7.0.1 for Mac does not move >0<

Comment: Although the way this answer is phrased makes it sound like Firefox is buggy, it's actually following the standard, as `0` is not a valid time value. More on that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145352/units-on-0s-transition-in-firefox/13145406#13145406) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/time).

Comment: @BoltClock that's because at the time I was still holding out hope that the W3C would choose consistency over arbitrariness.

Comment: This still seems to be an issue in Firefox 31.0. Glad it's an easy fix though +1

Comment: Is it possible to fix full background image transition in firefox too?