# Which CSS Minifiers/Compressors don't omit the unit of time values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, minify

The anser to the question "[Units on “0s” Transition in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145352/units-on-0s-transition-in-firefox)" points out that it is not valid to omit the unit of time values. My first but not main question would be:

#### Is this true? Is it for sure invalid to omit units in time values?

As far as I can see in the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values), regarding length values it says

> However, for zero lengths the unit identifier is optional (...).

Not so for values of other types, but at the same time it also does **not** say it is *invalid*. "[time - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/time)" very clearly says it **is** *invalid*.

So, just to be sure: Can anyone confirm it is **invalid** by additional references?

### Main question: Which minifiers/compressors do *not* omit the unit of time values?

In fact, even if it were valid, [Firefox](http://firefox.com) does ignore declarations like `a { transition: all .5s 0 }`

So, using a compressor/minifier that does **not** omit the unit seems important to me. Firstly Firefox will need it, secondly it might be necessary for all browsers in future if it **is** invalid and they change their engines accordingly.

---

Note: I'm developing in ASP.net and want to use the [Bundle Transformer](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/) for `System.Web.Optimization` namesapce. I need a compressor which I can use there. Either with a built-in implementation of the `IMinifier` interface or at least a usable library so I can write my own implementation of the interfaces.

I'll upvote answers with minifiers/compressors that at least have an API so it can be used programmatically. I'll accept the answer with a minifier/compressor with good compression that is locally usable with Bundle Transformer (which means no http request is needed).

---

With that said: **Please feel free to mention *any* minifier that does not omit the unit of zero time values** because I think this could be interesting for everyone, not just .net developers.

For now I tested the following tools:

- **[YUI Compressor](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/)**

  Just one example c# code so .net guys know what I'm talking about:

  ```cs
  public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
  {
      IBundleTransform yuiTrans = new CssTransformer(new YuiCssMinifier());
      var cssBundle = new Bundle("~/content/css/default", yuiTrans)
                                .IncludeDirectory("~/content/css", "*.css");
  }
  ```

  <del>YUI minifies CSS without omiting the unit of time values.</del>

  ---

  **Update Dec 9 '14**: Sadly, this is not true anymore. Thanks to [Torin Finnemann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2239615/torin-finnemann) who [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247507/which-css-minifiers-compressors-dont-omit-the-unit-of-time-values?noredirect=1#comment43167331_16247507) on this issue. You may test it yourself with this [Online YUI Compressor](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/).

  ---

  So if there is a declaration like

  ```css
  a {
      transition: all 0.5s 0s;
  }
  ```

  the YUI Compressor minifies it to

  ```css
  a{transition:all .5s 0s}
  ```

  Why not just using it? Well, currently I am, but YUI's compression level is not very good (e.g. `color: black` becomes `color:black` instead of `color:#000`). [CSS Minifier Comparison](http://www.codenothing.com/benchmarks/css-compressor-3.0/full.html) gives an overview. That's why I'm searching for possible alternatives.
- **Default compressor of `System.Web.Optimization`**

  I'm not sure, but if [this blog post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/566569/WebsiteplusPerformancepluswithplusASP-NETplus-plus) is right, `System.Web.Optimization` has it's own compressor implementation. It's definitly not [Microsoft Ajax](http://nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax) which produces different output in my tests. However, it minifies the above example to

  ```css
  a{transition:all .5s 0}
  ```

  As you can see it omits the unit and therefore is not an alternative.
- **[Microsoft Ajax](http://nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax)**

  Does omit the unit.
- **[`KryzhanovskyCssMinifier` based on Sergey Kryzhanovsky's CSSO](http://nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Csso/1.6.10)**

  This was the last minifier I tested, so I don't have that much experience with it yet, but it looks much more promising than the others. It is smart enough to minify to the following (added whitespaces for readability):

  ```css
  a{   -moz-transition:all .5s 0s;-o-transition:all .5s 0;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s 0 ;   transition:all .5s 0}
  ```

  As you can see, it omits the unit except for the vendor prefixed version `-moz-transition`. So, currently this does the job for Mozilla browsers. Firefox accepts the non-vendor-prefixed versions of `transition` since version 14.0 I think, but still recognize the prefixed versions. Since Firefox ignores the default statement because of the missing unit, it uses the prefixed one.

  Well, as I said this is the most promising minifier, but it is not a rock solid solution because Mozilla could someday remove the support for vendor prefixed statements in Firefox. Or, as I stated at the beginning of this post, if omiting the unit **is** invalid the other browsers could update their engines.

Conclusion: The question is still out there. If you know a minifier/compressor that does not omit the unit of zero time values, please share it.

Comment: From what I can see, the current version of YUI-compressor actually does remove the unit. It can be circumvented by specifying two decimal digits: .00s. https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/99

Answer (score 2):

Though they don't minify colors, the following two online minifiers retain the unit of zero time values.

http://cssminifier.com/

http://www.freeformatter.com/css-minifier.html

Comment: +1 for cssminifier because it comes with an API. Please keep us updated if you find more.

Answer (score 0):

Clean-CSS allows you to specify whether you want to strip units from zero values or not: https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#user-content-how-to-set-compatibility-mode

```
--compatibility *,-zeroUnits
```