# Overriding transition-delay issue on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I having issue to override transition-delay on firefox. Below example works as i expected in Chrome and IE but  at Firefox, before animation it is delaying. I am not able to override transition-delay on firefox before animation starts. I believe this is a bug but what is workaround of this problem?

Here is [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/QBXfB/2/)

Here is Html Codes

```
<button>move</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.box').addClass('move').on('transitionend',function(){
        $(this).removeClass('move');
    });
});
```

And CSS

```
.box{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:yellow;
    transition:all 1s ease 1s;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
.move{
    transition-delay:0;
    left:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to include a unit (seconds in this case):

```
.move {
    transition-delay: 0s; 
    left: 500px;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QBXfB/4/)

<sup>This answer explains why: [Units on "0s" Transition in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145352/units-on-0s-transition-in-firefox)</sup>

Comment: You are right, it works well. I couldn't guess this because it was working well in other browsers and also if we use zero value it is ussually redundant to use unit.