# Simple CSS3 animation is not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, css-animations, prefixfree

I am trying to Animate a div. What i am actually doing in the animation is translating the div to 100%. but the animation only works in chrome and it is not working in Firefox. i tried to add prefix and i  also included prefix-free.js plugin. Caniuse.com says firefox will support animations without prefixing. I have seen lot similar question in stack over flow. but most of them are using property's that are not yet supported in Firefox and other. But mine is very simple. I even tried by removing translation and background-color change. but it is also not working.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js' ></script>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    padding:3em;
}
.icon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    animation: test 1s linear 0 infinite normal both;
}
@keyframes test {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(50%);
        background-color: red;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
        background-color: yellowgreen;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mostwanted_cJ/e7qr2cmv/6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is invalid. Your zero `animation-delay` needs to have a unit, so it should be `0s`, not `0`:

```
.icon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    animation: test 1s linear 0s infinite normal both;
}
```

Unitless zeroes are only permitted for lengths, not times. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145352/units-on-0s-transition-in-firefox/13145406#13145406) for an explanation (the question is about transitions, but it applies to animations as well).

Answer (score 0):

Change your animation call to this,

```
.icon
{
    animation: test 1s linear infinite;
}
```

It seems firefox does not understands some short hand properties.

Answer (score -3):

Write your code like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            padding:3em;
        }
        .icon, .icon:hover {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: red;
            -webkit-animation: test 2s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            animation:test 2s;
        }
          /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            @-webkit-keyframes test {
                from {background: red;}
                to {background: yellow;}
            }

            /* Standard syntax */
            @keyframes test {
                from {background: red;}
                to {background: yellow;}
            }
    </style> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="icon"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```