# Why do I have to specify a unit identifier (e.g. 'px') when passing 0 as the only argument into the calc() function?

Tags: html, css, specifications

The [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-values) states:

> ...for zero lengths the unit identifier is optional (i.e. can be syntactically represented as the `<number>`‘0’).

This is why most of us drop the unit identifier when dealing with 0s, as `0px`, `0em`, `0%` and so on all evaluate to the same length.

The same documentation also states that the `calc()` function:

> ...can be used wherever `<length>`, `<frequency>`, `<angle>`, `<time>`, `<number>`, or `<integer>` values are allowed. Components of a `calc()` expression can be literal values, `attr()` or `calc()` expressions, or `<percentage>` values that resolve to one of the preceding types.

The problem here is that the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Internet Explorer treat `calc(0)` as an invalid expression. The `0` here is a value which resolves to a `<number>` type (as we're made aware from the first snippet I quoted in this post).

If we try and validate `width: calc(0)` through [W3C's own CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator), we're presented with the following error:

> Value Error : width `calc(0)` is not a width value : `calc(0)`

However if we try and validate `width: 1`, we're instead given the following error which appears to contradict this error:

> Value Error : width only `0` can be a length. You must put a unit after your number : `1`

---

### Example

In this example a `1px` red border is applied to each `code` element. In an attempt to override the border's width, the first has `calc(0)` specified as the border width, and the latter has `calc(0px)`.

```css
code {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
}

code:first-of-type {
  border-width: calc(0);
}

code:last-of-type {
  border-width: calc(0px);
}
```

```html
<code>border-width: calc(0);</code>
<code>border-width: calc(0px);</code>
```

For those using browsers which do not support CSS's `calc()` function, here is an image of the result I see in Chrome (v39):

[image: Example Image]

If we look at this in Chrome's Element Inspector, we'll see that `calc(0)` is indeed deemed invalid:

[image: Chrome Element Inspector]

---

Is there a reason behind why `calc(0)` is treated as an invalid expression? Is the number `0` not a value which is considered "literal"?

Comment: Interesting to note that this also applies to 0s as part of expressions (e.g. `calc(0 + 1px)`), meaning this isn't simply that implementations need to know the dimension of the calc result for dimensional analysis. But then, I don't see when this would be relevant: the 0 shorthand is for saving typing, but in a calc expression you can always just omit the 0s anyway. And any dynamic code generation can always specify a `px` suffix (or whatever is appropriate). So while it's an interesting edge case, I don't see any practical value to accepting it (and it would likely complicate the code)

Comment: @Dave oddly `0` can be used in multiplication: `calc(0 * 1px)`. Heck, you can even `calc(0 * 0px)`.

Comment: That makes sense; the rules of dimensional analysis say that the dimensions also get multiplied in that case, so you have (1) * (px) giving (px) which is valid. You would NOT be allowed to do `0px * 0px`, because that would give `0 px^2`, which is not a length. In fact, thinking about it that way, this makes sense. The calc expression sees 0 as a numeric constant (e.g. a ratio), and since it doesn't know how it will be used it can't infer a type to append. This means the calc expression returns a numeric constant, which is not a valid width (which can be length or percent)

Comment: All these "0s" in the question and comments are messing with me because "0s" in CSS can mean "0 seconds" :) Granted, it's not a length but a time (which makes it [exempt from the unitless zero rule altogether](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145352/units-on-0s-transition-in-firefox/13145406#13145406)), but still...

Comment: @BoltClock haha, you had me really confused there for a moment, wondering about the possibility of defining widths in seconds!

Comment: I'm not confident enough to post an answer of my own, but I did find this: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2010Dec/0479.html which seems to say that if you look really closely, the spec does in fact consider unitless zeros invalid for `calc()` lengths. It doesn't really explain why however, beyond "unitless zero is ambiguous", which is in line with what @Dave said.

Comment: @BoltClock nice find! You'd assume that a simple check for *'if calculated n is equal to 0'* would be all that's required to rule out ambiguity - especially as the computed value for `border-width` in Chrome becomes `0px` even if you specify `calc(0em)`.

Comment: "the possibility of defining widths in seconds": well once Hz are supported, you could technically do `width:calc(3s * 10Hz * 2px)`! (in fact, that sort of thing would also make 0 short-hand even more complicated: `width:calc(0 * 0 * 2s)` is valid if one of those 0's is Hz and the other is a length!)

Comment: @Dave: The spec doesn't allow mixing types anyway, so that would not be an issue altogether :)

Answer (score 3):

It's basically what @Dave and @BoltClock say:

Section 8.1.2 of that spec says that the resolved type of the math expression `calc(0)` is determined by the types of the values it contains, which for a NUMBER token like `0` is a <number> or <integer>. Neither of those types is valid as a `width` value, which takes a <length> or <percentage>, so the expression is invalid.

But if you use `0` as the value, it can be parsed as a <length>, per section 5 of the spec as you quoted.

`calc(0)` isn't syntactically (or lexically, as we see) equivalent to `0`, so section 5 doesn't apply to it.

---

Or were you asking a philosophical question about why the spec was written so?

Comment: Why would `calc(0)` *not* be equivalent to `0`?

Comment: I said that `calc(0)` is not _syntactically_ equivalent to `0`, and it should be obvious why: they are different strings, `calc(0)` starts with "`c`", etc.

Comment: `calc()` is a function, not a value, and the part you've summarised to me suggests that `calc(0)` should return the NUMBER `0`, which the user agent would treat as if `0` had been specified in the first place. The NUMBER `0` **is** valid as a `width` value, which I've quoted right at the start of my question (I can't link directly as w3's website seems to have a redirect loop at the moment). I don't feel that this answers the question because it doesn't give a definitive answer of why `calc(0)` is invalid - it only speculates.

Comment: "which the user agent would treat as if 0 had been specified in the first place" is where you're wrong. Read section 5 of the spec, which you quote: "can be **syntactically** represented as the <number> ‘0’". I think you're hung up not understanding the difference between syntax and semantics (which is common among people who've never written a parser). Yes, `calc(0)` resolves to <number> or <integer> `0`; but that's irrelevant to section 5.

Comment: The problem is that the part you're referring to is an example of what it can be syntactically represented as. It doesn't say that it must be the `<number>` 0 and not the result of the `calc()` function.

Comment: That's not what I read. It uses "i.e.", not "e.g.". This isn't just an example, it's a clarification of what's necessary. (Now, that may include "`0.0`" or "`+00`" or other syntactic equivalents, so not _just_ a literal "`0`".)

Comment: To clarify the syntactic distinction, read section 4.2: "A number... corresponds to the NUMBER token", vs. section 8.1.1: 'calc : "calc(" S* sum S* ")"'. So `calc(...)` is a "calc" expression, _not_ a NUMBER token, in the syntax, and is thus not syntactically a <number>.

Comment: the problem that I find there is that the `calc()` section states that `calc()` can resolve to `<number>`.

Comment: That resolution can only happen after a lexical analysis parses the tokens, builds the AST, matching it to the grammar rules, and evaluates the typed expression. That goes beyond the syntactic level. That's why I keep emphasizing [syntax vs. semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_%28programming_languages%29#Levels_of_syntax).