# CSS Animations not working in Firefox - pseudo

Tags: html, css, firefox, animation

I have some CSS animations that will not work in Firefox. They are applied to a pseudo element (:after) and all work fine in every other browser.

The animations are applied here

```
:after
{
    display:block;
    background:url('../img/snow.png'), url('../img/snow2.png') ;
    -webkit-animation: snow 15s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: snow 15s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: snow 15s linear infinite;
    animation-name:snow;
    animation-duration:15s;
    animation-timing-function:linear;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

And the animations themselves are here:

```
@-webkit-keyframes snow {
 0% {background-position: 0px 0px;}
 100% {background-position: 0px 1000px, 0 500px;}
}
@keyframes snow {
 0% {background-position: 0px 0px;}
 100% {background-position: 0px 1000px, 0 500px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes snow {
 0% {background-position: 0px 0px;}
 100% {background-position: 0px 1000px, 0 500px;}
}
@-ms-keyframes snow {
 0% {background-position: 0px 0px;}
 100% {background-position: 0px 1000px, 0 500px;}
}
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreicated!

Comment: Can you please provide the jsFiddle for this? It makes it easy to work with it then..:-)

Comment: you can see the live working example @ socialsanta.co - the snow should be animated but currently is not for Firefox.

Comment: This might put some light on your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844520/css-animation-works-in-chrome-but-not-in-firefox and if not there are many SO thread.....plz research.....

Comment: I have researched and tried following all of the steps I could find ... the above isn't relevant as I have used s to signify unit for each of my declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that your keyframes have different-length lists for background-position.  It looks like Gecko doesn't allow interpolation between different-length background-position lists.  I filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=945600

In the meantime, simply using

```
0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px;}
```

in your keyframes should make this work, I believe.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes if you have your firebug or any other web developer tool is turned on then CSS does not work.

Comment: Honestly, it becomes the solution due to that.

Comment: Whenever my firebug is on and I try some action on the webpage, it doesnt work and when I turn it off, it works. @Akki619

Comment: Hi - I was testing on a PC that doesn't have any dev tools on it. so this isn't the case unfortunately